# Display problems in admin dashboard when creating a new theme from scratch

Tags: theme-development, widgets, sidebar, dashboard

**EDIT 2:** I have found the code it was within my stylesheet! I had a class called "wrap" :( phew! Thank you everyone

**EDIT:** I removed my stylesheet and now everything is displaying properly but I still have the problem with the widget collapsing, also it isn't saving! 
If I click save it looks like it's saving, then stops. When I re-load the widgets page the widget I added is gone.

so I have been creating a theme in WordPress from scratch. It is my first time doing it, and I'm enjoying it, but I've run into a problem. The admin dashboard is looking weird, well, the widgets page anyway, and maybe some others?

Here is what it looks like:

[image: WP Dashboard problems]

The sidebars are directly underneath the widgets instead of on the right hand side making it harder to drag drop.

Also, when I drag a widget to the sidebar, it show the title and text field for a second then collapses just showing delete and save.

I have checked other themes and there is no problem so it lies within my theme.

I have tried removing my functions.php file, nothing changed, tried removing every other php file one by one and nothing was changing. I don't know where the problem could be? It is obviously coming from my theme folder.

Thanks,

Joe.

Comment: Are your frontend stylesheets being loaded in the admin area? It's near impossible to tell just from a screenshot and a visual description

Comment: Yeah I literally just thought it might be the stylesheet, one of my classes may be clashing. It's in the main theme folder along with all php files as when I was learning someone told me not to put it in a css folder. I know now I can use get_template_directory_uri() right? Like I have done with my JS file.

<?php 

wp_enqueue_style ( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri());
wp_enqueue_script( 'jc-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jc-script.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );

?>

Comment: Joe, add the code that registers/enqueues your theme stylesheet to your question.  Unless you are writing an admin theme, your theme's stylesheet should not be loading when viewing the dashboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joe, as already said in this post, just by the image it looks like the dashboard style sheet of management is breaking. Try the right mouse button and click inspect.
The area in question must be within the div with class.
If not, try restoring your wp.